# Input button click is not invoked through JavaScript in IE9

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-9

We have a hidden input button which is used to submit the form. The submit is invoked using a Javascript. The script is invoked on click of another button. The click event is invoked in IE8 (it also works fine in IE5, IE6, and IE7). In IE9 the click event is not getting invoked. Any clue, or solution would be helpful.

Below is the aspx and the JavaScript code of the button.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Proceed" Style="display: none;" OnClick="btnProcedi_Click"></asp:Button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("<%=Proceed.ClientID%>").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"()"` in ASPX:

```
Style="display: none;" OnClick="btnProcedi_Click();"
```

and also

```
document.getElementById("<%=Proceed.ClientID%>").onclick();
```

in Javascript